# Get HTML up to child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to get an HTML string, or `document-fragment` of an element, up to a certain element?

For example, say I have the following HTML

```
<div id="blocks">
    <div class="block">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li id="target">Some List Item</li>
                <li>Some Other List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is just an example, the HTML will actually be much more complicated and with more levels**

What I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
$(".block").html("#target")
```

And get a HTML string such as:

```
<div>
    <ul>
         <li id="target">Some List Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Notice how there's only one list item in the resulting HTML**

I want to get all the HTML of the `.block` element, up to the `#target` element

Thanks!

Comment: That's a completely different question; I don't see how it's a possible duplicate

Comment: Can you post your expected HTML result. I'm still not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Felix See my question, I've updated it to make it a little clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//clone the original `.block` and get it's `#target`.
var cloned = $('#target').closest('.block').clone().find('#target');
var temp;
//go up the cloned parents and remove child that is not in the path of `#target`
while(true){
    temp = cloned.parent();
    var flag = false;
    temp.children().each(function(i, el){
        if(flag)
            $(el).remove();
        if($(el).is(cloned))
            flag = true;
    });
    if(cloned.is('.block')) break;
    cloned = temp;
}
```

After this the `cloned.html()` is what you need.
See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fx5pU/

And note that this will **not** change the original HTML in contrast to some other solutions suggested here.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fx5pU/1/ It almost works! But it strips out some elements

Comment: not work see here http://jsfiddle.net/Fx5pU/2/ the test is not there in the list but it should be there.

Comment: Check this version http://jsfiddle.net/Fx5pU/3/. If that's not the expected answer, please provide the expected answer for this input HTML

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

Clone the parents up to ".block" and remove the siblings of "#target".

```
var newBlock = $('#target').parents("div.block").clone();
newBlock.find('#target').siblings().remove();
```

Check out the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2p4hp/26/)

Comment: I can't do it that way, the HTML could vary significantly. The only constant thing I know is which element I need to get HTML up to.

Comment: $("#target").parentsUntil(".block");

Comment: Just tried that, it gets the HTML of the `<ul>` element

Comment: Ignore the parentsUntil one. See the updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div.block').not('#target').remove()
```

Comment: That will remove all child elements that aren't `#target`. The HTML will vary significantly.

Comment: @MichaelBates Then what do you need please specify properly.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Etn7/1/)

```
$('.block #target').nextAll().remove();
```